# Redis on Heroku connection error : 127.0.0.1 instead of REDIS_URL

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, redis, express-session

What is the proper setting for using express-sessions and connect-redis when deployed on Heroku. Heroku says to use the REDIS_URL param, but it must not be working because I keep getting error that it is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1

```
const session = require('express-session')
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)

const store = new RedisStore({
  connectionString: process.env.REDIS_URL,
  logErrors: true
})
```

I have tried setting 'connectionString' as 'client' that gives me error, host, error. What is the proper setting I am missing here and can't find anywhere online.

Comment: Answer: I had to change connectionString to url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change connectionString to url

This comes directly from the documentation for the npm package connect-redis found here... https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22307328)

Comment: how does this not answer the question? the answer to the question is to change 'connectionString' to 'url'

Comment: @JamieTom you could improve your answer by adding link with reference.